# PHP import HEAD content using READFILE but unique page title

Tags: php

I'm using READFILE to import the same page head content on multiple web pages, but I need to change the page title.

I know that I could just import only the contents of the HEAD tag (and not the tags themselves) and add a separate line afterwards just for the TITLE tag but I want to understand the concept of importing text and customising just one small part of it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer in another post:
[PHP to place page-generated title into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729652/12616680)

On webpage.php

```
<?php 
$pageTitle = "Test";
include('header.php');
?>
```

In header.php

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </title>
</head>
```